# Is scalaz-xml deprecated?

Tags: xml, scala, scalaz

I haven't found any reference to the xml module in Scalaz github repo. In the branch [series/7.1.x](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/series/7.1.x/xml/src/main/scala/scalaz) it is but not in the [latest](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). Also, there is not any documentation about xml processing with Scalaz (this is weird). Any idea why?

As far as I know, there is no real alternative to big XML processing. Anti-xml is abandoned (there is an updated version by no.arktekk, though) and scala-xml has performance issues.

Do you recommend me any project that worths a try? I do know ScalesXml but I don't know very much about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not just deprecated, [dead](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/commit/52b4eda945b53346cb403ffbd18afbfd81939460) (it was removed from the 7.2 branch last summer after being deprecated in 7.1—see the [release notes for M6](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/wiki/7.1.0-M6) for details).

This isn't really the place for library recommendations, but I've had mixed experiences with Scales—it's nicely designed in some ways, kind of weird in others, and not very widely adopted (or well-documented). [Rapture XML](https://github.com/propensive/rapture-xml) might also be worth a look. There's not currently a good answer, though—the Scala XML library situation is [pretty much a wasteland](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/396962072157638656).

Comment: I can report that PRs to scala-xml will languish even longer than PRs to scala/scala. Darn, I also forgot on Wed. to announce that scala/scala was looking for a maintainer!

Comment: Also overlooked was the Scala community's new guidelines for accepting PRs from Typesafe. https://github.com/scala/scala-lang/pull/290#issuecomment-89325450

Comment: The situation on scala-xml has improved a lot in the last year. scala-xml 1.0.6 came out with some fixes, and some further pull requests have been merged recently. There is still a PR backlog, but that's partly for lack of community help reviewing PRs. If there's an open PR you'd especially like merged, leaving review comments on it might help.